# Make table rows on a single line HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am kinda beginner and sorry if my question seems too basic.

I have a table that looks like:

```
--------------------------------------------
|Column 1              |Column 2           |
--------------------------------------------
|this is the text      |text               |
--------------------------------------------
```

I wanna make it so:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Column 1              |Column 2           |this is the text      |text               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sample of HTML is:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table width="300px">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>this is the text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make 100% width of table and make tr display as inline

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}

tr {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table width="300px">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>this is the text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
<html>

<body>
    <table width="300px">
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>this is the text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

You had two `tr` tags, that means two rows, and you said you only need one row so I used only one `tr` tag

Comment: I am sorry, but this one is not a solution for my case... The thing is that I had generated code (not on my side), which is divided into rows with over 3000 rows and I could not use anything else except for html+css. So I had to place multiple rows on a single line

Comment: So you would want it to be like this column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | text1 | text 2 | text 3 | text 4 etc...

Comment: Yeah, exactly so

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS

```
table { table-layout:fixed }
td { overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap }
```

The `table-layout:fixed` rule says "The cell widths of this table depend on what I say, not on the actual content in the cells". This is useful normally because the browser can begin displaying the table after it has received the first `<tr>`. Otherwise, the browser has to receive the entire table before it can compute the column widths.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to create a 4 column table.
You declared a 2 column table, (the column is declared with TD)
you have only to declare 4 TD
Try this:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table width="300px">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>this is the text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this one is not a solution for my case... The thing is that I had generated code (not on my side), which is divided into rows with over 3000 rows and I could not use anything else except for html+css. So I had to place multiple rows on a single line.